# Can't access website through public IP

Tags: iis, ip, public

I have a website hosted on IIS for windows server, working through localhost, local IP and hostname.

this server has a public IP.

i hosted another website on the same server and IIS that is working when browsing through localhost and local IP, but when i try to browse it using the public IP, it is not working.

when i put the public ip only (without the port in bindings) in the browser i get the default IIS page, when i add the port to it, it doesn't work and throws

**PUBLIC IP** took too long to respond

what am i missing?

Comment: You have to delete the default page with the administration tool. And then you can apply your website to the matching address. It would also be helpful if you could mention the tools you are working with.

Comment: @Norukh thanks for the quick reply. by administration tool you mean the IIS, and by default page you mean default document?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant

Comment: @Norukh okay basically, i have a joomla cms website, hosted on IIS. i am using only one tool which is the IIS manager. regarding the default document i changed the order so the index.php comes first. the weird thing is that the public IP is connecting the IIS, but when i add a port it can't connect. i added the public IP to the bindings with the "all unassigned", should i do that?

Comment: The "all unassigned" option is correct you can find more about it here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1239609. Maybe you should check again the path in your IIS configuration to the correct path of the joomla php files e.g. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite.com